# My module setup does not run in Magento

Tags: magento-enterprise, php-5.4, install-script

In my module i have an sql script, the module runs but the setup script is not executed. From `core_resource` table I have `nav_setup | 0.1.1 | 0.1.1` but table is not installed?

I have created log from `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup` class `_getAvailableDbFiles()` method and it is returning my module

```
$filesDir   = Mage::getModuleDir('sql', $modName) . DS . $this->_resourceName;
```

**result:** `C:\xampp\htdocs\magento1131\app\code\local\ICS\NAV\data\nav_setup`

**config.xml**

```
<global>
 <models>
            <nav>
                <resourceModel>nav_resource</resourceModel>
                <nav_resource>
                    <class>ICS_nav_Model_Resource</class>
                    <entities>
                        <nav>
                            <table>throttle</table>
                        </nav>
                    </entities>
                </nav_resource>
            </nav>
        </models>

        <resources>
            <nav_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>ICS_nav</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </nav_setup>
            <nav_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </nav_write>
            <nav_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </nav_read>
        </resources>
</global>
```

**my sql script:**

```
<?php

$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("

-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('nav_throttle')};
CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('nav_throttle')} (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `last_api_call` timestamp NULL,
  `minute_throttle` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='api limit';
");

$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: what is the file name of your setup script?

Comment: @fschmengler install-0.1.1.php

Comment: If 0.1.1 is not the initial version, it should be `upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php`

Comment: @fschmengler, 0.1.1 is initial version

Comment: @fschmengler, see updated my thread

Comment: Always try to follow the magento naming convention for modules. For example try avoiding caps. Ics_Nav should work. It is really important... 
I'm not sure about your version but maybe in your case the directory should be named /nAV_setup/

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete the entry nav_setup in your core_resource table. and then refresh any one of the magento page,

Now you can find your table installed. I guess you are having some issue in your sql code. Better run it as plain sql in your mysql terminal/phpmyadmin, If its successfully creating table, You can proceed with the same script.

Yes actually, the way you are calling your table is wrong. Ideally it should be like this..

```
$this->getTable('modulename_throttle')
```

Because in our config.xml we have to define the table name inside those tags. Your config.xml should look like below.

```
    <modulename_resource>
          <class>Namespace_Modulename_Model_Resource</class>
          <entities>
            <throttle>
              <table>my_custom_tablename</table>
            </throttle>
          </entities>
    </modulename_resource>
```

Whenever you are calling the above code $this->getTable(modulename_throttle), It will go,find to the tags from config.xml and give the values of the node

Hope this helps. Cheers.!

Comment: I have cleared cache again it's same problem. see i have updated my thread with sql script is it wrong?

Comment: see updated my thread

Comment: Check my updated answer dude